# How can I remove http or https using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
<script>
document.write('<img src=//testURL.comaction?item=' + window.location.href + '>');
</script>
```

If the current window.location (url) contains http or https I would like to remove it.

Update:
Is there a reason for the two vote downs? My question was clear

Comment: `window.location.href` returns full URL. Are you trying to remove more than only "http" or "https" from `window.location.href`? What is expected resulting string?

Comment: `var withoutPrefix = window.location.href.toLowerCase().replace(/http:/g, "").replace(/https:/g, "");` - This will remove `http:` and `https:` from your url using a simple `.replace()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove just `http`/`https`: `window.location.href.replace(/^http(s?)/i, "");`

To remove `http:`/`https:`: `window.location.href.replace(/^http(s?):/i, "");`

To remove `http://`/`https://`: `window.location.href.replace(/^http(s?):\/\//i, "");`

These are all case-insensitive and only remove from the start of the string

Comment: If you need to remove the colon, try `/http(s?):/`

Comment: Add the "i" modifier for case-insensitive matching `/http(s?)/i`

Comment: @SteamDev good catch!  I also added an anchor to the start of the string

Answer (score 3):

Simple regex would do the trick.

```js
const removeHttps = input => input.replace(/^https?:\/\//, '');

const inputs = ['https://www.stackoverflow.com', 'http://www.stackoverflow.com'];

inputs.forEach(input => console.log('Input %s, Output %s', input, removeHttps(input)));
```

However, a cleaner approach might be to instead just combine `${document.location.host}${document.location.pathname}${document.location.search}`. It's longer, but you don't have to do any regex.

- `host` is something like `stackoverflow.com`
- `pathname` is something like `/questions`
- `search` is something like `?param=value`

Together they give the whole URL without the protocol (which is `document.location.protocol`, by the way).

Comment: Thanks for the detail. Awesome

Answer (score 2):

If you want to only replace `http` or `https`, you should use `window.location.href.replace(/http(s?)/, '');` as Kieran E suggested. If you want to always remove the protocol, you could use `window.location.href.replace(window.location.protocol, '');`.

Comment: To remove the `//` as well: ```window.location.href.replace(`${window.location.protocol}//`, '')```